# Присвоение номера элементу в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например, есть список со словарями.

```
list = [{"name":"a","number":1},{"name":"b","number":2}]
```

В этот список нужно добавлять, удалять словари, а так же изменять значения в ключах.

```
a = input()
number = 1
for i in list:
    number += 1
task = {"name":a,"num":number}
list.append(task)
```

Что бы найти ключ нужно написать ее номер.

```
a = int(input())
    for i in list:
        if a == i['num']:
            print(i['name'])
```

Но проблема в "счетчике".Он не идеальный. Нужно что то лучше.

```
number = 1
for i in list:
    number += 1
```

Comment: 1) Не называйте переменные именами функций, например до вашего `list  = ` код `print(list("123"))` будет работать, назовите лучше нейтрально `items` 2) ваш цикл с `number` можно укоротить: `number = len(items)`

Comment: Поддерживаю предыдущего комментатора. Если очень хочется назвать list, то можно назвать list_.

Comment: 1) Эту переменную использовал только для примера
2)Спасибо.Но мне надо еще подправить вопрос, я забыл кое-что добавить

Comment: Не стоит так делать даже в примерах: не путать людей, не вызывать гнев людей, не привыкать к плохому. Я сейчас напишу развёрнутый ответ по Вашему вопросу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас очень замороченная реализация очень простой операции.

```
number = 1
for i in list_:
    number += 1
```

Данным циклом Вы пытаетесь подсчитать количество элементов в списке. Почему бы это не сделать так:

```
number = len(list_)
```

Тогда имеем

```
a = input()
number = len(list_)
task = {"name":a, "num":number}
list_.append(task)
```

Далее, можно не объявлять переменную `task`:

```
a = input()
number = len(list_)
list_.append({"name":a, "num":number})
```

Произведём ещё несколько модфикаций

```
list_.append({"name":input(), "num":len(list_)})
```

Но, возможно, `input()` имеет смысл вынести в отдельную строку, дабы обработать `EOF`.

Данные модификации также важны по нескольким причинам:

- Вы избавляете себя от необходимости придумывать названия переменных (иногда важно, всё-таки создать новую перменную, особенно когда кода в одной строке становится слишком много), что под час бывает сделать не просто. Называть же переменную абы как -- не хорошо, поскольку код, состоящий из переменных `a`, `b`, `c`, `xix` и т.п. сложно поддерживать.
- Во-вторых, на создание переменной тратится время и память (в данном случае -- это мелочь), но в больших масштабах может играть роль (Насчёт питона я не уверен, как создаются переменные, но подозреваю, что на это тратятся указанные ресурсы)

Кроме того, я предлагаю Вам сделать замену либо на `enum`, либо на именованные кортежи. Словари здесь не актуальны, поскольку у Вас есть заранее фиксированное количество ключей. Почему бы строки-ключи не заменить на инты? Они весят на порядок меньше.

Данное замечание важно, поскольку при масшатбировании Вашего куска кода на большое количество данных, скорее всего Вы столкнётесь с проблемой нехватки оперативной памяти. После этого Вам придётся сильно переделать Ваш алгоритм, который к тому моменту, верятно, будет связан с большим количеством других систем и алгоритмов.

Для того, чтобы создать `enum`, мпортируем класс:

```
from enum import Enum
class Keys(Enum):
    Name = 0
    Number = 1

list_.append({Keys.Name:input(), Keys.Number:len(list_)})
```

В питоне `enum` умеют [интересные вещи](https://pynsk.ru/blog/2016/02/13/enum/).

Аналогичный пример можно привести и для [namedtuple](https://apirobot.me/posts/namedtuple-in-python):

```
from collections import namedtuple
Keys = namedtuple('Keys', ['name', 'number'])
list_.append(Keys(input(), len(list_)))
```

P.s. И, наверное, `number` нужно, всё-таки, заменить на `count`.